# Why is the snake coordinates not changing the direction to the other side

Tags: python, pygame, 2d-games

I know the code is not neat and organized but I'm just trying to make the thing work and after that I'll start cleaning and organizing everything into place

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

#assigns thingys to window adjustments
size = width, height = 750, 750
white = 255, 255, 255
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game")

#The coordinates and size of the snake square thingy
x = 200
y = 200
w  = 20
h = 20
vel = 10
vertical1 = 9000
vertical2 = 0 

while 1:
    
    #Delays the movement so you can see snake thingy fps
    pygame.time.delay(25)


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    #gets the presses to move the snake
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x= x - vel

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x= x + vel

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y = y + vel

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y = y - vel

    screen.fill(white)

    #The snake thingy
    snake = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (x, y, w, h))

    #Borders for the frame thingy 
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), (14, 10), (14, 800), 30)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), (734, 10), (734, 800), 30) 
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), (9000, 734), (0 , 734), 30) 
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), (9000, 24), (0 , 24), 30) 
  
    if x < 30 and y == y:
        x == 700
        y == y
    pygame.display.update()  
pygame.quit
```

I'm facing a problem here, theoretically if the coordinates of the snake becomes less than 30 then it changes the coordinates to 700 so it could be on the other side. However that's not seem to be working so I'm trying to figure out what i did wrong

> if x < 30 and y == y:
>
> x == 700
>
> y == y

Comment: It's a typo: `x == 700` is a comparison. You have to use an assignment `x = 700`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok u just have a typo in it:

Change those lines:

```
x==700
y==y
```

To:

```
x = 700
```

Comment: Oh, you successfully copied my comment. "Typo" questions should not be answered but closed. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I'm sure you know this, you just want to grab some reputation points. I don't give a down vote, because the answer is technically correct. However, the answer shouldn't exist as it won't be useful to other users. It's just a typo.

Comment: Thanks.. noted.. do you suggest me to delete the answer then?